# Record number of occurrences of specific substring in VECTOR of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm testing a small program in order to create a larger one.
I have a vector of 3 strings:

```
 pass
 pass
 TEST pass pass
```

I want to search the vector for the substring "pass" and record how many times "pass" is found in the vector of strings.

So basically I want it to return the number 4 (4 instances of the substring "pass")

Code looks like this

the strings are stored in the vector myV1

```
if (find(myV1.begin(), myV1.end(), "pass") != myV1.end()  )
{
    passes++;
}
```

when I do this it finds "pass" once and ignores the others.

I can't get a loop to work either. It tells me that it found however many instances of the substring "pass" for as many times as i loop through.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Find always returns the first occurence of element, then the result of using loop would be the number of times the loop has been executed.

Comment: Couldn't you use for_each and just compare values?

Comment: yea i was trying to figure out how to do that. just did it now. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: [here](http://ideone.com/7eKVHx) you can find the working code with an online compiler.

All you need is two loops, one for iterating over the vector elements, and one that iterates over each element while counting the desired word occurrence in that particular element. The external loop summarizes it then.

You could use string::find for the internal loop, and the external loop is the regular one with the iterators.

You will need the snippet below to work properly with C++98/03 and C++11 as well.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> stringList;
    stringList.push_back("pass");
    stringList.push_back("pass");
    stringList.push_back("Test pass pass");
    string searchWord = "pass";
    int searchWordSize = searchWord.size();
    int count = 0;

    for (vector<string>::iterator iter = stringList.begin(); iter != stringList.end(); ++iter) {
        // Avoid the overlapping search word. If that is needed, replace
        // pos+=searchWordSize with ++pos
        for (size_t pos = 0; pos < (*iter).length(); pos+=searchWordSize) {
            pos = (*iter).find(searchWord, pos);
            if (pos != string::npos)
                ++count;
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    cout << "Count: " << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have built and run the code with the following commands:

- `g++ main.cpp`
- `./a.out`

The output will be `4` as expected.

Comment: @Laszlo Papp okay that works perfectly. now i'll have to examine that snippet and learn it myself, haha. thank you for saving me hours of headache.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop vector and  use `std::string::find` to find the occurrence of `"pass"` in each string.

To count occurrence of a substring correctly, you need to record `postion` of first occurrence then increment position and continue the search.

```
int count(const std::string& s, const std::string token = "pass")
{
  int n(0);

  std::string::size_type pos = s.find(token);
  while (pos != std::string::npos)
  {
    pos = s.find(token, pos + 1);
    n++;
  }
  return n;
}

int main()
{    
 std::vector<std::string> v = {"pass", "pass", "TEST pass pass"};

 int total(0);

 for (auto& w : v)
 {
   total += count(w);
 }
 std::cout << total << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is C++11 solution, and will not work with different versions.

Comment: @LaszloPapp only the shortened `v` and `for`? C++11 has already arrived.